# Trigger jenkins build if only a specific file is changed

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have my codebase in GIT. There are 5 files in the code base i.e.

- File1
- File2
- File3
- File4
- File5

I want to trigger a jenkins build only if File 2 is changed.Please note that, post the build is triggered it should pull the entire codebase.

I tried using poll SCM, but the problem is that the build gets triggered if any of the files in the repository are changed.I want to trigger it only if File 2 changes.

Is it possible?

Comment: I guess it's easier to handle it, when you have different branches. Then you can work with git hooks https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: I do have 2 branches, master and dev....i have configured the source code management such that it pulle the dev branch only.....but i want to setup a jenkins build if only a file changes.....i am afraid that i may not have the access to change the hooks....is there any other workaround for it?

Comment: @Philj0 your suggestion conflicts with my interpretation of VCSs. Different branches are not there to store different data on the long term.

Comment: I meant, its easier to setup a jenkins build or a git hook if you have only this file on the branch. I don't know how to set up a jenkins build triggered by this file, but it's possible to do it with a git hook and no different branch for that. Thought it was easier for him to handle it this way.

Comment: Okay guys, so i think I am able to write hooks...post researching I zeroed down to the fact that for doing this we need to write a server side post receive hook.....can any one guide on how to watch one particular file using a hook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

1. Configure your Jenkins job to `Trigger builds remotely`.

   This enables a build trigger URL in the form of `JENKINS_URL/job/MYJOB/build?token=TOKEN_NAME`. You have to specify the token name yourself.
2. Configure a git post-receive hook on your repo to call that trigger.

   The script for the hook is usually under `.git/hooks/post-receive`. The post-receive hook runs after the entire process is completed and can be used to update other services or notify users.

   A post-receive hook gets its arguments from stdin, in the form `<oldrev> <newrev> <refname>`.

   You can retrieve the file list from the new HEAD commit and then only proceed to the next step if it includes `File2`. Something like this (not tested):

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   while read oldrev newrev refname
   do
       # list of changed files for a commit
       filelist=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $newrev)
       if [[ $filelist == *"File2"* ]]; then
           # call the URL according to your build trigger config
       fi
   done
   ```

[More details on git hooks.](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Answer (score 5):

When you configure the git checkout in Jenkins, there is a button to add additional behaviors. One of those options is to `Polling ignores commits in certain paths`. I haven't actually used it, but it is my understanding that this will do what you are looking for. There is an option for includes and excludes. You would just use the includes, I believe.

Comment: I dont think this is working for me for some reason.....can you provide some more details around it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to install FS trigeer plugin and then you can include and exclude in jenkins configuration

[Link Here  - FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin)

Comment: Bad description and don't add link without good explanation and answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using this plugin and it worked like a charm.

You need to install the plugin Generic Webhook Plugin in Jenkins and provide the following values in configuration.

variable  : changed_files

expression   :     $.commits[*].['modified','added','removed'][*]

expressionType: JSONPath

Under options:
text: $changed_files

expression: path/to/your/file

https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/gitlab/gitlab-push-specific-folder.feature

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please add some explanation and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, you should probably do this in github actions and it would be very simple, unless like me you're forced to use Jenkins then this is for you.
So after a bit of searching for this answer I was able to do it with [generic webhook trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/), which is the comment above me that got 0 votes, I'll try to be a bit more clear on the process:

1. Install the generic webhook trigger plugin to Jenkins there you can pull variables from the [github webhook payload](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push)
2. You can then create a job using the generic webhook trigger plugin
3. I used 3 variables from the github webhook payload: (written in the plugins json path expression)

   - $.ref (branch)
   - $.head_commit.modified (squashed commit modified files array)
   - $.html_url (the repo url - since I want to do action on repo if changed)
4. In Job under the generic webhook trigger section you can use the optional filter to decide if the job should be triggered or not. for me it was a simple regex of checking branch master and that the "VERSION" file is among the modified files
5. Go to your Github repo and configure in settings > hooks > new webhook with url http://JENKINS_URL/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke (I picked it to trigger on PUSH events which is what matters to me)

Debugging:
Github is actually great on this, once you configure the webhook you can see every POST sent to Jenkins and see the Jenkins response. There's also good [examples](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/tree/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd) in the [generic webhook trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/) docs.

Notes:
Pay attention that different github actions have different payloads: a PR action will not have any modified files array etc.